# Checking the type of a methods return value

Tags: java, types

I want to check if a method has returned a particular type of value of and want to use it in `if` statement.

I have a class called `DBConn` and there I have a static method called `dbConnect()` which returns a `Connection` type value if had a successful connection otherwise throws an exception.

In my `main class` I want to do something like

```
if (DBConn.dbConnect() == Connection) {
    // then do something
}
```

Note that I am calling this static function inside the if condition.

How can I realize this in Java?

Comment: Why do you want to use an `if` statement there when your method either return a valid `Connection` object or throws an exception?

Comment: I am new to java. Just exploring it. Thank you

Comment: A) Sounds like XY problem  (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what do you actually try to solve B) your question implies that you are lacking knowledge of absolute **basics** of Java. A person who has no idea about basics should stay away from advanced stuff such as DB usage. Learn to crawl before trying to run!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if a method has returned a particular type of value

Use the `instanceof` operator.

```
if (DBConn.dbConnect() instanceof Connection) { ... }
```

It returns `true` if the left operand can be cast to the right operand. That is, if it either is `Connection` or a subtype of it, like some `FastConnection extends Connection`.

It is described in detail in the [JLS$15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not `null` and the reference **could be cast** ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)) to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.

---

Note that your description sounds like you don't even need to check that. You say

> It returns `Connection` or throws an exception

If the method throws the exception your current code will fail and the `instanceof` doesn't help at all.

Instead you should to **catch the exception** ([official tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)):

```
try {
    Connection con = DBConn.dbConnect();
    // Do something with con
} catch (ConnectionFailedException e) {
    System.err.println("Connection failed!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also note that if you plan to use the result of the method later, you should probably save it in some variable. Otherwise you will need to repeatedly call the method which is just unnecessary and might introduce some problems depending on the implementation.

```
Connection con = DBConn.dbConnect();
// Rest of code
```

Comment: This method call almost certainly should be put in a local variable first unless you know that calling it repeatedly is harmless. (In theory it could return a different type or a new expensive resource each time)

Answer (score 0):

If the method is going to return a `Connection` or throw an exception, the correct way to handle this is

```
try {
   Connection connection = SomeClass.someConnectionProvidingMethod();
} catch ( SomeException ) {
   ... handle exception ...
}
```

That is because the language itself would have to be broken to receive a non-Connection from a method like

```
public Connection someConnectionProvidingMethod() {
   ... implementation here ...
}
```

Now, if you really want to spend CPU cycles, time, and electricity checking if the language compiled correctly and the JVM is running properly, you could also do

```
if ( someVariable instanceof Connection ) {
  ...
}
```

but as you described it, the above statement could never be false, so you might as well have written

```
if ( true ) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if ( 1 == 1 ) {
   ...
}
```

I recommend not putting in `if` statements that test conditions which are constant; because, they mislead other people reading your code, and will mislead you when you revisit your older code.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped very much